# Errno 256 No more mirrors to try centos 6.6

Tags: centos, meta

I am trying to install metasploit on crentos 6.6 server

now when i tried to  yum install or `wget` or even git any bundle i got errors

then after alot of search i found that it is a problem in the DNS so i tried to edit  /etc/resolv.conf

and add 8.8.8.8 as name server it worked fine but after server reboot or even eth0 restart it keeps returning without the modifications i made

this is my  /etc/resolv.conf content

```
# No nameservers found; try putting DNS servers into your
# ifcfg files in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts like so:
# DNS1=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
# DNS2=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
# DOMAIN=lab.foo.com bar.foo.com
```

is there any solution for this problem

Comment: yes this is what really in my  /etc/resolve.conf

Comment: This really belongs in either http[superuser(http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) or [Unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) given it's not about programming but installation/configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting your networking configuration from DHCP but your DHCP server is failing to give you any DNS server addresses.

Did you try doing what that file tells you to do? Because that will "fix" your problem for you (assuming you don't choose to get your DHCP server fixed to provide you with DNS servers correctly).

Answer (score 1):

I remember I got similar errors with CentOS.
Problem was: No internet connection.

First check a network connection:

```
#ping google.com
```

If there is no connection. You have to debug this first.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check location `/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-3.2.repo`
2. Delete all the irrelevent repositories in that location but be careful at that. Ex:- delete datastax repo which may be present
3. Run `yum clean all`
4. Run `yum update`